# LPWSTR to wstring c++

Tags: c++, wstring

I would like to read utf-8 test from a .dll string table.
something like this

```
LPWSTR nnW;
LoadStringW(hMod, id, nnW, MAX_PATH);
```

and after that I would like to convert the `LPWSTR nnW` to `std::wstring nnWstring`.
I tried in this way:
   LPWSTR nnW;
LoadStringW(hMod, id, nnW, MAX_PATH);

```
const int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,
                                       0,   // no flags required
                                       (LPCSTR)nnW,
                                       -1,  // automatically determine length
                                       NULL,
                                       0);

std::wstring nnWstring(length, L'\0');

if (!MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,
                         0,
                         (LPCSTR)nnW,
                         -1,
                         &nnWstring[0],
                         length))

MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)nnWstring.c_str(),  L"wstring", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```

After that in the MessageBoxW only shows the first letter.

Comment: What have you tried? There's a really obvious solution. It might interest you to know that it's the same as `char *` to `std::string`, due to both actually being `std::basic_string<CharT>` with different, predefined `CharT`s.

Comment: Why are you calling `MultiByteToWideChar`?  Both `LoadStringW` and `wstring` already use wide characters.

Comment: Also, DLL string tables aren't UTF-8.  They are UCS-2.

Comment: I saw your other question come and go.  Any luck storing Unicode strings in your resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No conversion or copying needed.

```
std::wstring nnWString(MAX_PATH, 0);
nnWString.resize(LoadStringW(hMod, id, &nnWString[0], nnWString.size());
```

Note: Your original code causes undefined behavior, because it writes using an uninitialized pointer.  Surely not what you wanted.

Here's another variation:

- http://msmvps.com/blogs/gdicanio/archive/2010/01/05/stl-strings-loading-from-resources.aspx

Comment: if I try your solution I get this errors:
error: `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const wchar_t*'`
error: `initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc = std::allocator<wchar_t>]'`

Comment: @Carl: Ok, the two-argument constructor is needed, to specify an initial length.

Comment: OK thanks it works but If I use a messagebox to show the result I get this:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/130402/message_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Comment: @CarlMark: Your question talks about UTF-8.  Did you put UTF-8 codepoints inside a UCS-2 string table?

Comment: @Carl: I think I see your problem.  When using non-ASCII characters, you need to use long string constants in the resource definition file.  e.g. `L"Fájl"`  You may need to use hexadecimal codes as well.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I should use the hexadecimal codes in my rc file. I found this page: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and if I would like to use a special character for example: `Á` I should use this in my rc file: L"\xc380". But I get some weird chinesee letter. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ohh... I found what was the problem I should use the UNICODE codes not the HEX codes. I don't know why, but when I use the HEX code it doesn't work but if I use the UNICODE code it works well.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, the problem is that you need to use the value from the left-hand column: `L"\x00C0"` and not the UTF-8 encoding.  The Unicode values are in hexadecimal also.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to read utf-8 test from a .dll string table. something like this

Generally, string tables in Windows are UTF-16.  You're trying to put UTF-8 data into one.  The UTF-8 data is being treated like "extended" ASCII, so each byte is being expanded to two bytes with zero bytes between them.

You should probably put UTF-16 data in the string table directly.

If you must store UTF-8 data in the resources, you can put it into an RCDATA resource and use the lower-level resource functions to get the data out.  Then you'll have to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 to store it in a wstring.